# Removing Application from Multitask Bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

As My application supports background task I have an `Exit` button which will call `exit(0)`. My application gets closed properly but still an instance of the App is on Multitask Bar, i.e. bar when `Home` key is pressed twice.

Is there is any way to remove the App from Bar using code?

Open for any suggestion.

Comment: I like how you manage to capitalize every word except "I".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not allowed to exit your application programatically, it is against the guidelines and if you do this your app will almost certainly be rejected by Apple's software review team.

The only way an app can ever be closed is by the user pressing the home button. You can't have your own button for that.

You can have a button to stop your app from doing anything in the background of course.

Comment: To add to this great answer, the apps you see in the `Multitask Bar` are just apps you started. If your app is in this bar does not mean it is running.

Comment: Don't try to exit the application forcing a crash. I already saw a guy saying this is a smart way to override the guidelines but this can make your app to be rejected.